# Flutter: RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a ListView but when I import the list_form.dart class i get this error. Maybe I made some mistakes with the layout because if I try to run it inside the main file I don't get this error.

This is the error:

```
    I/flutter (12956): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12956): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (12956): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (12956): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter (12956): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (12956): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (12956): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter (12956): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter (12956): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter (12956): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter (12956):
I/flutter (12956): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (12956): #0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1133:15)
I/flutter (12956): #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1186:6)
I/flutter (12956): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1616:9)
I/flutter (12956): #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #19     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter (12956): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #21     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter (12956): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #23     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:381:13)
I/flutter (12956): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #25     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:141:11)
I/flutter (12956): #26     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:339:7)
I/flutter (12956): #27     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:211:7)
I/flutter (12956): #28     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:355:14)
I/flutter (12956): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #32     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #33     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1192:11)
I/flutter (12956): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #37     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #38     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1192:11)
I/flutter (12956): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #46     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #50     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #52     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #55     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2884:13)
I/flutter (12956): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #57     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:520:15)
I/flutter (12956): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #59     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #61     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #63     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #65     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #67     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #69     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (12956): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (12956): #71     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:147:13)
I/flutter (12956): #72     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1506:7)
I/flutter (12956): #73     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:765:18)
I/flutter (12956): #74     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:270:19)
I/flutter (12956): #75     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:674:13)
I/flutter (12956): #76     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter (12956): #77     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter (12956): #78     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter (12956): #79     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
I/flutter (12956): #81     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (12956): #82     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (12956): #83     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (12956): (elided one frame from package dart:async)
I/flutter (12956):
I/flutter (12956): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (12956):   RenderViewport#925a8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956):   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#8e8f7] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter (12956):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#67ae5] ←
I/flutter (12956):   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#17eb8] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ←
I/flutter (12956):   NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← ⋯
I/flutter (12956):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (12956):   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter (12956):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (12956):   axisDirection: down
I/flutter (12956):   crossAxisDirection: right
I/flutter (12956):   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#c4917(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
I/flutter (12956):   ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#2fecf,
I/flutter (12956):   ScrollDirection.idle)
I/flutter (12956):   anchor: 0.0
I/flutter (12956): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (12956):   RenderSliverPadding#74d62 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956):     RenderSliverList#5c56d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#925a8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#925a8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#8bbda relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#209b4 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#a9641 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#9f5b4 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#47944 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e17a8 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#a2328 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#02607 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#79164 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 310 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (12956): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
```

This is the list_form.dart class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ListFormState createState() => new ListFormState();
}

class ListFormState extends State<ListForm> {
    List<String> products = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                      return new Text(products[index]);
                    }
                  ),
                  new IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                    onPressed: () { },
                  )
                ],
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              ),
              new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Prodotto"
                ),
                onSubmitted: (String str) {
                  setState(() {
                    products.add(str);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]
          )
        )
      );
    }
}
```

This is the app_base.dart class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../UI/list_form.dart';

class AppBase extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new AppBaseState();
}

class AppBaseState extends State<AppBase> {
  bool _pressed = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: new Scaffold(
        body:
          new ListForm(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Skeeper'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          tooltip: 'Test',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _pressed = !_pressed;
              });
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Don't worry if there is some unused code, it's a work in progress and this error just stopped me continuing what I was doing.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

The problem is that you are placing the `ListView` inside a Column/Row. The text in the exception gives a good explanation of the error.

To avoid the error you need to provide a size to the `ListView` inside.

I propose you this code that uses an `Expanded` to inform the horizontal size (maximum available) and the `SizedBox` (Could be a Container) for the `height:`

```
    new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200.0,
            child: new ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: products.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                return new Text(products[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    )
```

,

Comment: SizedBox partially works.  If you resize the window to a size smaller than the sized box you get errors.   Should you use the sized box with an expandible? Getting bottom overflow errors

Answer (score 187):

You can add some code like this

```
ListView.builder{
   shrinkWrap: true,
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution for long lists. [From documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html): "Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes".

Answer (score 125):

**Reason for the error:**

`Column` tries to expands in vertical axis, and so does the `ListView`, hence you need to constrain the height of `ListView`.

---

**Solutions**

1. Use either `Expanded` or `Flexible` if you want to allow `ListView` to take up entire left space in `Column`.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
         child: ListView(...),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

2. Use `SizedBox` if you want to restrict the size of `ListView` to a certain height.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(
         height: 200, // constrain height
         child: ListView(),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

3. Use `shrinkWrap`, if your `ListView` isn't too big.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       ListView(
         shrinkWrap: true, // use it
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This is by far the best and concise answer! I wonder though why in my case with the same composition of `Column` wrapping a `ListView` I receive an error if I use `Expanded`, but works fine with `SizedBox` though 

Comment: @boldnik What are other widgets in your `Column`, you can actually ask it as a question or simply start a conversation on chat with me in case you think it can be handled in comment section.

Answer (score 17):

use `shrinkWrap: true`,

With shrinkWrap: true, you can change this behavior so that the ListView only occupies the space it needs (it will still scroll when there more items).
If you set it to true, the list will wrap its content and be as big as it children allows it to be.

like this.

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
.........
 }
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Placing your list view in a Flexible widget may also help,

```
Flexible( fit: FlexFit.tight, child: _buildYourListWidget(..),)
```

Answer (score 7):

[image: i]

**I used this code to fix the issue of displaying items in the horizontal list.**

```
new Container(
      height: 20,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: array.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return array[index];
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your ListView in an Expanded widget

```
 Expanded(child:MyListView())
```

Comment: it does not work if the `Expanded` is one of the children of a `Column`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similir problem, but in my case, I put a row in the leading of the ListView, and it was consuming all the space, of course. I just had to take the Row out of the leading, and it was solved. I would recommend to check if the problem is a larger widget than its container can have.

```
Expanded(child:MyListView())
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem may arise in the use of all kinds of lists, which will be solved by placing the command `shrinkWrap: true,`
Example:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: 6,
       **shrinkWrap: true,**
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            color: Color(0XFF323232),
            child: Column(children:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Always resolve this error in one of the following three ways:

1. Wrap your ListView with `Expanded` widget.
2. Wrap your ListView with `SizedBox` and give it a specific height.
3. You can add below your listView this line:    `shrinkWrap: true`,

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be because List view is inside a Column, it’ll make the list view non scrollable.

So, better use this:

```
ListView.builder{
   shrinkWrap: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar problem, but in my case I was put a row in the leading of the Listview, and it was consumming all the space, of course. I just had to take the Row out of the leading, and it was solved. I would recomend to check if the problem is a widget larger than its containner can have.

Answer (score 0):

My app started crashing with the same error just completely out of the blue.

I really appreciate the other answers mentioned here on this page. But none  worked for me. I was on Flutter 2.0.0 and upgrading to Flutter 2.2.2 fixed the issue without changing anything in my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Expanded widget will fix that problem, mainly that error occurs when you user multiples widgets with dynamic sizes in a column or a row

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are using a Column/Row ensure to specify the size they should occupy e.g.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: const [
      CircularProgressIndicator(),
      SizedBox(
         width: 15,
       ),
       Expanded(
         child: Text("Data Laoding"),
       )
     ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I was using an SvgPicture widget inside a SizedBox widget and instead of specifying the height property in the SizedBox I did it inside the SvgPicture widget.

If that is your case, then I recommend you specify the height of the SizedBox.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the list view inside a **Container** and specify the **width**.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ListView.builder(..)
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

See, wrap with expanded, no matter of anything.
Flexible widget also sometimes doesn't works.
Hope, this will be helpful.

Rendering,
Parent widget error,
Assertion are basic errors.

This will catch fears in a programmer.