# ReorderableListView: Exception: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

TL;DR - **How to achieve `shrinkWrap = true` in a `ReorderableListView`**?

I was trying to create a `ReoderableListView` with `Column<-Container` as parent, this error occured.

```
I/flutter (32618): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (32618): BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.


I/flutter (32618): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderStack#23840 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter (32618):   creator: Stack ← _Theatre ← Overlay-[GlobalKey#dc153 ReorderableListView overlay key] ←
I/flutter (32618):     ReorderableListView ← StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> ← Column ← Padding ← Padding ← Container ←
I/flutter (32618):     BoardCard ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← ⋯
I/flutter (32618):   parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (32618):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=328.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter (32618):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (32618):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter (32618):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter (32618):   fit: expand
I/flutter (32618):   overflow: clip
I/flutter (32618): This This RenderObject had the following child:
I/flutter (32618):     child 1: _RenderLayoutBuilder#55d3d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

This would have been fixed very easily if it was `ListView` by using `shrinkWrap = true` but `ReorderableListView` does not have the this property.

**Here is the code**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _listTitleStyle =
        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
    final _listSubTitleStyle = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      color: Color(0xff7D7373),
    );
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        widget.cardTitle,
                        style: _listTitleStyle,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.cardSubTitle,
                        style: _listSubTitleStyle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: widget.query,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
                return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) {
      print("debug 1 ${snap.data}");
      print(TodoItem.fromSnapshot(snap, snap.reference).toString());
    });
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex){},
      children: snapshot
          .map((data) => TodoTile(TodoItem.fromSnapshot(data, data.reference), key: UniqueKey(),))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Wrap ``ReorderableListView`` inside a container and give it a height

Comment: @Abdulrahman Doing that is not an option because i want the height to be sum of heights of the children, **Similar to WrapContent**

Comment: It's probably because it's inside a `Column` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801201/flutter-renderbox-was-not-laid-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by replacing `ReorderableListView` by the package [flutter_reorderable_list](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list), it accepts a child (Widget) unlike ReorderableListView which accepts children (List)

Its implementation is a bit more complex. You can look at the [example](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) to get some understanding of implementing it correctly.

Comment: If you have a simplified example, it would be great if you posted it here :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Abdulrahman Falyoun. you just have to make the height dynamic and adjust it based on the number of items in the list.

```
 Container(
      height: (list.length * 40).toDouble(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        children: list.map((item) {
          return getItem(item);
        }).toList(),
        onReorder: _onReorder,
      ),
    )
```

or if it's within a column, then have it wrap with `Expanded()`

Answer (score -3):

**use Columnto listview and apply shrinkWrap = true**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _listTitleStyle =
        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);
    final _listSubTitleStyle = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      color: Color(0xff7D7373),
    );
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Listview(
        shrinkWrap = true
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        widget.cardTitle,
                        style: _listTitleStyle,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.cardSubTitle,
                        style: _listSubTitleStyle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: widget.query,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
                return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) {
      print("debug 1 ${snap.data}");
      print(TodoItem.fromSnapshot(snap, snap.reference).toString());
    });
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex){},
      children: snapshot
          .map((data) => TodoTile(TodoItem.fromSnapshot(data, data.reference), key: UniqueKey(),))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
```