# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#4a60a NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter, dart

When I running the code I find this error in the `DEBUG Console` as the below shown error:

```
Restarted application in 2,804ms.

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown during performLayout():[39;49m
Leading widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget.
'package:flutter/src/material/list_tile.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1353 pos 7: 'tileWidth != leadingSize.width'


[38;5;248mEither the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
[39;49m

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      _RenderListTile.performLayout[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      RenderObject.layout[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      RenderPadding.performLayout[39;49m
[38;5;244m#5      RenderObject.layout[39;49m
[38;5;244m#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderListTile#a7a4d relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
[38;5;244mRenderObject: _RenderListTile#a7a4d relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
    [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)[39;49m
    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=0.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)[39;49m
    [38;5;244msize: MISSING[39;49m
    [38;5;244mtitle: RenderParagraph#47706 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT[39;49m
        [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mconstraints: MISSING[39;49m
        [38;5;244msize: MISSING[39;49m
        [38;5;244mtextAlign: left[39;49m
        [38;5;244mtextDirection: ltr[39;49m
        [38;5;244msoftWrap: wrapping at box width[39;49m
        [38;5;244moverflow: clip[39;49m
        [38;5;244mlocale: en_US[39;49m
        [38;5;244mmaxLines: unlimited[39;49m
        [38;5;244mtext: TextSpan[39;49m
            [38;5;244mdebugLabel: (((englishLike subhead 2014).merge(blackCupertino subtitle1)).copyWith).merge(unknown)[39;49m
            [38;5;244minherit: false[39;49m
            [38;5;244mcolor: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff03a9f4))[39;49m
            [38;5;244mfamily: WorkSans[39;49m
            [38;5;244msize: 16.0[39;49m
            [38;5;244mweight: 600[39;49m
            [38;5;244mbaseline: alphabetic[39;49m
            [38;5;244mdecoration: TextDecoration.none[39;49m
            [38;5;244m"Sign Out"[39;49m
    [38;5;244mtrailing: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#705a3 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
        [38;5;244mparentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=0.0, 0.0<=h<=56.0)[39;49m
        [38;5;244msize: Size(0.0, 24.0)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mchild: RenderExcludeSemantics#60a3d relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
            [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
            [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=0.0, 0.0<=h<=56.0)[39;49m
            [38;5;244msize: Size(0.0, 24.0)[39;49m
            [38;5;244mexcluding: true[39;49m
            [38;5;244mchild: RenderConstrainedBox#bc3b1 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
                [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
                [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=0.0, 0.0<=h<=56.0)[39;49m
                [38;5;244msize: Size(0.0, 24.0)[39;49m
                [38;5;244madditionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=24.0, h=24.0)[39;49m
                [38;5;244mchild: RenderPositionedBox#c7d80 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=0.0, h=24.0)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244msize: Size(0.0, 24.0)[39;49m
                    [38;5;244malignment: center[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mtextDirection: ltr[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mwidthFactor: expand[39;49m
                    [38;5;244mheightFactor: expand[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#a7a4d relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#0b562 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#7c546 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#6507d relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#d89dc relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#b5666 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListTile[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#ace43 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mColumn[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#4e86c relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mContainer[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderColoredBox#3fe26 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mColumn[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#48686 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

and this is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import '../providers/properties.dart';
import '../providers/cities.dart';
import '../providers/property.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/properties_grid.dart';
import '../app_theme.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentTab = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = false;
      });
    } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = true;
      });
    }
  }
  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool multiple = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final properties = Provider.of<Properties>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: _showBottomBar
            ? BottomAppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                notchMargin: 10,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 155,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 1;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.home,
                                  color: currentTab == 1
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Home',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 1
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                      // Right Tab bar icons

                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 60,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 3;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.view_list,
                                  color: currentTab == 3
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Property List',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 3
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            minWidth: 77,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                // currentScreen =
                                //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                currentTab = 4;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.location_searching,
                                  color: currentTab == 4
                                      ? Colors.blue
                                      : Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Map',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: currentTab == 4
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const SizedBox();
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      appBar(),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                          future: getData(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return const SizedBox();
                            } else {
                              return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                create: (context) => Properties(),
                                child: PropertiesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child:
                    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: AppTheme.dark_grey,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      multiple = !multiple;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope some one could figure with me this problem and how to solve it :)...

May be I think that there's a problem with the height of the `SizedBox` as in this question [Flutter: RenderBox was not laid out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801201/flutter-renderbox-was-not-laid-out), but I tried to add the height I found the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you put your appBar() in a column. That should be in the appBar property of the Scaffold widget. 
You need to use the AppBar() Widget in the Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Put Screen title here'),
    actions: <Widget>[IconButton(
      icon: Icons.location_on,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
           multiple = !multiple;
        });
      }),
    ],
   ),
),
```

You are setting height and width of the appBar manually but you are fighting the Flutter framework by doing so.

Comment: Yes exactly because the app bar is the part of the Column