# Vertical alignment of a list inside a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, expanded

I have the following screen which displays a list of categories retrieved from a REST API. My MainCategoryProvider takes care of it.

I have an AppBar, a tip text (my custom tipText widget), the list of categories and a custom BottomBar with an action button and the app menu

```
import 'package:choooze_app/models/main_category_model.dart';
import 'package:choooze_app/providers/main_category_provider.dart';
import 'package:choooze_app/widgets/bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:choooze_app/widgets/tip_text.dart';
import 'package:choooze_app/widgets/title.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:choooze_app/widgets/action_button.dart';

class MainCategoryListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _mainCategoryProvider = Get.find<MainCategoryProvider>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: title(context, titleText: 'maincategory_list_title'.tr),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0, 16.0, 16.0),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              tipText(context, text: 'maincategory_list_tip'.tr),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<MainCategoryModel>>(
                  future: _mainCategoryProvider.getMainCategories(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      final mainCategories = snapshot.data!;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: mainCategories.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var mainCategory = mainCategories[index];
                          return InkWell(
                            child: Container(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5.0, 0, 5.0),
                              decoration: index < mainCategories.length - 1
                                  ? BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                          color: Color(0xffcccccc),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : BoxDecoration(),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(Get.locale == Locale('en')
                                      ? mainCategory.nameEn
                                      : mainCategory.nameFr),
                                  Text(
                                    !mainCategory.active
                                        ? 'maincategory_detail_inactive'.tr
                                        : '',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFFD06706),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {},
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              BottomBar(
                child: actionButton(
                  context,
                  buttonText: 'maincategory_list_actions_new'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This gives me the following results => [Capture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vphqr.png)
It looks good, but I would like the list of elements to stick to the bottom of the screen, right above the green button.

How can I achieved that?

I try to play with column settings but without success.
If a wrap the ListView.builder inside a Column widget with a MainAxisAlignment.end, I get the followin g error:

````
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#82eda NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
main_category_list_screen.dart:44
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```
````

Comment: " but I would like the list of elements to stick to the bottom of the screen, right above the green button." how.  do you want the button to come up, the top to come down, insert an empty gap at the top, or the text to get REALLY TALL?  You can't change the laws of physics.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me.
It works with a fixed size widget. but with a listBuilder it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you want the list to start from the bottom, then try using MainAxisAlignment.end in the mainAxisAlignment field in Column.

```
Column(
  ...
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  ...
);
```

Comment: I tried that. It looks like the way to go.
I replaced the ListView.builder by a simple Text, I wrapped it in a Column widget just like you suggested and the text is displayed at the bottom.

When I replace my Text with the ListView.builder I get the following error:


════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#82eda NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView

Comment: I think this post will help you solve that - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801201/flutter-renderbox-was-not-laid-out
I remember getting the same error and this post helped me with it.