# Flutter: How to show a list inside another list

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a UI like below:

[image]

My UI has an inner list and an outer list and the data count is dynamic.

**Sample Json:**

```
{
    'type': 'adjective',
    'meaning': [
      {
        'description': 'description 1',
        'example': 'example 1'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 2',
        'example': 'example 2'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 3',
        'example': 'example 3'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 4',
        'example': 'example 4'
      },
    ]
},
{
    'type': 'noun',
    'meaning': [
      {
        'description': 'description 1',
        'example': 'example 1'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 2',
        'example': 'example 2'
      },
    ]
},
{
    'type': 'verb',
    'meaning': [
      {
        'description': 'description 1',
        'example': 'example 1'
      },
    ]
},
{
    'type': 'adverb',
    'meaning': [
      {
        'description': 'description 1',
        'example': 'example 1'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 2',
        'example': 'example 2'
      },
      {
        'description': 'description 3',
        'example': 'example 3'
      },
    ]
},
```

How can I create a UI like this? Using what kind of widgets I can do this? Is it possible to add the sample json on the code?

Comment: Your history of asking Flutter questions is confusing me. 

1) You clearly know how to ask a decent question because you've done so ~10 times already just within the Flutter tag, yet this question shows none of that :( If you haven't already (although I doubt it, given your 3K rep), thoroughly read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 2) In lots of your previous Flutter questions, you add your own answer later on. The issue here is that your answer is usually just based off of the accepted answer (given it worked for you), so it’s not adding anything new. A new answer should be a new way to solve the problem. In these cases, if you *really* want to show others what your final code was (which isn’t necessary!), I would recommend editing your original post and adding it there. :)

Comment: 3) Most (if not all) of your previous Flutter questions, as well as your questions in other tags, have solutions which likely could have been solved by doing some light research or going through a few tutorials on the respective technology. Users may typically ask one or two of these types of questions when first starting with a new technology, but to ask them at the rate and quantity at which you are suggests you have not done enough prior learning about the technology! (here, Flutter)

Comment: Flutter has some of the *best* tutorials and documentation I’ve seen. I guarantee you would have known the answer to all of the questions you’ve asked about Flutter up to this point had you read through the first section of pages on [docs.flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui) and [dart.dev/guides](https://dart.dev/guides). Please take a read, you’ll find it very useful! :)

Comment: Going forward, when learning a new technology or if you come across a problem you don’t know how to solve, try your best to find the answer yourself online. Knowing what to Google to find an answer is a skill in itself which you’ll undoubtedly get better at over time. If you can’t find a direct answer to your question, then consider if your problem is due to a lack of understanding or knowledge of how the technology you’re using works. If so, give a proper read of the technology’s documentation, tutorials, getting started pages etc before going any further.

Comment: Remembering this will benefit you greatly. I hope you find this advice helpful, and happy coding! :)

Comment: @dwb Thanks for your all advices, going forward I will follow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1 :** You can create the UI like the image you shared by nested list view.

Here is the code : (you can modify it as per your requirements)

NestedListView.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '.../model/Word.dart';

class NestedListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Word> data;

  const NestedListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          List<Meaning> innerList = data[index].meaning;

          return Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Text(data[index].type.toString().toUpperCase()),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: innerList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final product = innerList[index];
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: Column(

                          children: [
                            Text(product.description),
                            Text(product.example),
                          ],
                        )),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Question 2 :**
Here is the model file which will take care of the nested list data.
Word.dart

```
class Word {
  final String type;
  final List<Meaning> meaning;

  Word({
    required this.type,
    required this.meaning,
  });

  factory Word.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Word(
      type: json['type'],
      meaning: List<Meaning>.from(
        json['meaning'].map((meaning) => Meaning.fromJson(meaning)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'type': type,
    'meaning': meaning.map((meaning) => meaning.toJson()).toList(),
  };
}

class Meaning {
  final String description;
  final String example;

  Meaning({
    required this.description,
    required this.example,
  });

  factory Meaning.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Meaning(
      description: json['description'],
      example: json['example'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'description': description,
    'example': example,
  };
}
```

Let me know whether it solves your problem.

**Edit 1**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final json = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {
      'type': 'adjective',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 3',
          'example': 'example 3',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 4',
          'example': 'example 4',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'noun',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'verb',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      'type': 'adverb',
      'meaning': [
        {
          'description': 'description 1',
          'example': 'example 1',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 2',
          'example': 'example 2',
        },
        {
          'description': 'description 3',
          'example': 'example 3',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Word> words = json.map((json) => Word.fromJson(json)).toList();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: NestedListView(data: words),
    );
  }
}
```

**You can solve renderflex error by debugging where it occurs.**

Comment: Where we can give the json data?

Comment: RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout. I am getting this error.

Comment: Check edited answer for your queries.

Comment: I have tried adding the both ListView.builder inside of an Expanded widget, then tried the SizedBox with a specific height and tried adding the `shrinkWrap: true`.  BUt none o0f them worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801201/flutter-renderbox-was-not-laid-out

Comment: It is working fine on a new project, when I integrate it to my real project, I am getting this errors. So is the error occurs due to any of my existing layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Hi To show a list inside another list from JSON data in Flutter, you can use nested ListView.builder.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
  {
    'type': 'adjective',
    'meaning': [
      {'description': 'description 1', 'example': 'example 1'},
      {'description': 'description 2', 'example': 'example 2'},
      {'description': 'description 3', 'example': 'example 3'},
      {'description': 'description 4', 'example': 'example 4'},
    ]
  },
  {
    'type': 'noun',
    'meaning': [
      {'description': 'description 1', 'example': 'example 1'},
      {'description': 'description 2', 'example': 'example 2'},
    ]
  },
  {
    'type': 'verb',
    'meaning': [
      {'description': 'description 1', 'example': 'example 1'},
    ]
  },
  {
    'type': 'adverb',
    'meaning': [
      {'description': 'description 1', 'example': 'example 1'},
      {'description': 'description 2', 'example': 'example 2'},
      {'description': 'description 3', 'example': 'example 3'},
    ]
  },
];

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final item = data[index];
    final type = item['type'];
    final meanings = List<Map<String, String>>.from(item['meaning']);

    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text(type),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: meanings.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, subIndex) {
              final meaning = meanings[subIndex];
              final description = meaning['description'];
              final example = meaning['example'];

              return ListTile(
                title: Text(description),
                subtitle: Text(example),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout. I am getting this error.

Comment: I have tried adding the `ListTile` and `ListView.builder` inside of an `Expanded` widget, but again the same error.